# Problem in printing specific character of an array after using strcat() function

Tags: string, arrays, c

```
    a[80000], b[40000];
    scanf("%s %s", a, b);
    strcat(a,b);
    printf("%c%c%c", a[0], a[1], a[2]);
```

Let's say if I input *a* = "**LORD**" and *b* = "**VOLDEMORT**" (without quotes), and concatenated both strings, to make "**LORDVOLDEMORT**".
Then, I would like to print first 3 characters from the concatenated string. So, in my opninion, the output result should be, "**LOR**" *(first 3 characters of the concatenated string)*, on the otherhand the result my compiler is showing is, "**LVE**".
Where am I wrong?
I'm new to the C language.

Comment: what types are `a` and `b`? `int`?

Comment: declare `a` and `b` as `char a, b;`

Comment: Your first line is not valid C, and this is not a [mcve].

Comment: @usr2564301: Its perfectly valid in C, just obsolescent.

Comment: Well, my C compiler rejects it out of hand – and when explicitly declaring it an `int`, it spits out lots of additional errors (something something *incompatible pointer type*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for your printout is that the compiler treats `a` and `b` as an integer arrays since you have not specified the type. Older compilers would let you go away with it and default the type to `int`.

So you effectively declared `int a[80000]; int b[40000];` For your program to work as you expected you should declare them with `char` type:

```
char a[80000], b[40000];
```

Now explanation for your **"LVE"** output. This is actually quite logical.
You have to understand how your array `a` sits in the memory:

```
 LORD VOLD EMOR T\0
 1234 1234 1234 12??
 a[0] a[1] a[2] a[4]
```

The explanation follows:

Every element of `a` is an `int` which occupies 4 bytes in the memory. You initialized the `ints` with the characters (your letters). Every `int` 'consumed' `4` characters.

Since you are not printing `a[0]` as `int` but you use `%c` so `printf` takes just first BYTE out of `a[0]` and prints `L`.

`a[1]` starts in memory from `V` so `V` would be printed.

`a[2]` starts in memory from `E` so `E` would be printed.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you've declared `a` and `b` as `int` arrays, but you're using them as `char` arrays.  This *should* give you a warning from your compiler (always use -Wall or the equivalent on you compiler and pay attention to the warnings).

The fix is simple; declare them as `char`:

```
char a[80000], b[40000];
```

Comment: Should you not precise that a *missing* type here in a declaration makes it default to `int`? (And then only in compilers old enough to not mark this as an error...)